'SignInForm' object has no attribute 'request'
I'm trining to set remember_me in forms.py insted of views.py via def clean_remember_me.
but it dosn't work and give me error !
forms.py
class SignInForm(forms.Form):
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),label=_('Remember me'), required=False)
    def clean_remember_me(self):
        remember_me = self.cleaned_data['remember_me']
        if not remember_me:
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

views.py
class LogInView(GuestOnlyView, FormView):
    template_name = 'log_in.html'
    form_class = SignInForm


share the view where you use the form. By default there is indeed no self.request

ok i done .....

Is your form an ordinary ModelForm/Form? or did you inherit from the Django auth forms?

Can you explain why you are trying to use self.request when it does not actually exist?  Did you write this code yourself, or did you copy from some example?

i want use session in form insted of view

@SOFArminRh - in my reply I explained why your solution “use query in form” can cause an error

In django usually you don't need to use request. By default Django dont have request.
in my projects i like to initiate form with request in initial's:
Myform(data, initial={..., 'request':request, ...}) 

after, in form instance you can use it as:
request = self.initial['request']

For your example you can override in your view get_initial method:
class LogInView(...):

    def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_initial(*args, **kwargs) | {'request': self.request}

But according to Django-way-programming, you should do it not in the clean_field method of the form. Because if the form is not walid, then the changes to request.settings are already done. This is wrong.
Instead to do something in form, you should use this logic in View:
class LogInView(...):
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        if not form.cleaned_data.get('remember_me'):
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)
        return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)

In this case, the session will only be cleared if all data is correct. And, of course, in this case you don't need to have a request in the form.

you need pass the request to the form like this:
[your_form_class](request.POST, request=request)

And in your form class:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request") # store value of request 
        print(self.request.user) 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

And then you can do:
def clean_remember_me(self):
        remember_me = self.cleaned_data['remember_me']
        if not remember_me:
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

I hope this can help you.

Your solution is wrong, because if the form is not valid and the clean_ method is called - the expiration date will already be set. And by the way. you need to override init for your solution.

Yes you right, but my approach was only to show how can pass context to the form.

I understand, but also in your case you need in additional to override init, in my answer you dont need to do it.
